# Compare size of each cell in Unix Scripting

Tags: unix, awk, scripting, string-length

I want to compare each cell size/length and change its content depending on its length.

The current table is of format

```
AB
CD
AB
AB
CD
155668/01
AB
1233/10
```

I want to replace the cells which have length more than "2" to DE.

Output

```
AB
CD
AB
AB
CD
DE
AB
DE
```

I tried

```
awk -F "," '{ if($(#1) > "2") {print "DE"} else {print $1 }}'
```

It says syntax error.
 If I use `wc -m` in place if `$(#` the output is same is the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
$ awk '{print (length($1)>2?"DE":$1)}' f
AB
CD
AB
AB
CD
DE
AB
DE
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use `sed`:

```
sed '/^..$/!s/.*/DE/' file
```

In `awk`, you could say:

```
awk '!/^..$/ { $0 = "DE" } 1' file
```

In both cases, the idea is the same: if the line does not consist of exactly two characters, replace the whole line with `DE`. In the case of `sed`, the whole line is `.*`, in the case of `awk`, it is `$0`.

Comment: Both are working very well. Thank you. Can u please explain the code.

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic way would be:

```
awk 'length($1) > 2 { $1 = "DE" } 1'
```

Comment: Did you mean to assign to `$1`?

Comment: @MichaelVehrs: Yes thanks. Just make an edit next time :-)